# Descending almost-contained subsets of $\omega$

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Let $A$ be an infinite subset of $\omega$ such that $\omega\setminus A$ is also infinite.

Under the Continuum Hypothesis is there a sequence $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ of subsets of $\omega$ such that

$A_0=A$;

$|A_{\alpha+1}\setminus A_\alpha|<\omega$; and

$|A_\alpha\setminus A_{\alpha+1}|=\omega$

for every $\alpha<\omega_1$?

Comment: Do you want $\subseteq^*$ or just finite differences? Because the answer is yes in either case, but for different reasons. Please settle on a version before I put any more energy into writing an answer...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would like for $A_{\alpha+1}$ to be contained in $A_\alpha$, up to some finite error.

Comment: As regards the current question, the constant sequence $A_\alpha=A$ works... Second, your axioms on the sequence make no relation between $A_\alpha$ and $A_\beta$ except when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ differ by addition by an integer. Please write your question more carefully. (Your last edit doesn't address my second sentence. Currently it's obvious to arrange a sequence of length $2^{\aleph_0}$.)

Comment: @YCor I would like the elements of the sequence to be distinct if possible

Comment: Obligatory keyword reference: $\frak t$, by the way.

Comment: Well, I have to insist that it's still trivial (in ZFC): for every non-successor cardinal $\alpha<2^{\aleph_0}$, choose an infinite subset $B_\alpha$, so that the chosen subsets $B_\alpha$ have pairwise infinite symmetric difference. Define $B_{\alpha+n}$ as $B_{\alpha+n-1}$ minus a point. Finally define $A_\alpha=B_\alpha\times\omega\subseteq\omega^2$.

Comment: Since @YCor has answered (in a comment) the question as asked and has suggested the probably intended modification to make it nontrivial, and since Nik Weaver has answered the nontrivial version, I'm voting to close.  (I'd favor reopening if (and only if) a different nontrivial version were proposed.)

Comment: The corrected version seems indeed as interpreted by Nik. It simply restates as: does the poset $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/\mathrm{fin}$ have a decreasing chain of type $\omega_1$? this is actually very standard and even in this version might be more suitable for MathSE.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, easily. Consider all well-ordered sequences $(A_\alpha)$, of any length, such that each $A_\alpha$ is infinite and satisfying your almost containment condition. Make one such sequence less than another if the first is an initial segment of the second. Zornicate to get a maximal such sequence, and it is easy to show that a maximal sequence cannot have countable length.

Comment: One should add, CH has nothing to do with it. Although it is consistent that a maximal one does have length $\omega_1$ which is strictly smaller than the continuum.

Comment: @Nik Thank you, your assumption was correct too.  I would also be interested in a more constructive (inductive) proof if it exists, because I am trying to apply this to construct a particular example.

Comment: It's not what I mean. I mean that one should ask some relation (other than just being distinct) between $A_\alpha$ and $A_\beta$ for all $\alpha<\beta$, not only between $A_\alpha$ and $A_{\alpha+n}$ for $n<\omega$.

Comment: @YCor For my particular purposes I'm not sure I need any particular relation between non-consecutive sets. But you suggest an interesting variation.

Comment: So you just consider the poset $\omega_1$ as a disjoint union of plenty of copies of the poset $\omega$.

Comment: YCor is right, you want to require $A_\beta\setminus A_\alpha$ to be finite for all $\beta > \alpha$.

Comment: Sorry for asking the following stupid question: What is the difference between a sequence $(A_\alpha)$ and a sequence $(A_\alpha)$?

Comment: @JoelAdler what?

Comment: @MonroeEskew Sorry for asking the following stupid question: What is the difference between a sequence $(A_\alpha)$ and a well-ordered sequence $(A_\alpha)$?

Comment: @JoelAdler in the latter case, we are saying that the index set is well-ordered.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Thanks! That's what I thought. I was a bit confused as we use ordinals, so the index set is assumed to be well-ordered.